# Question about operator==( const std::shared_ptr& lhs, const std::shared_ptr& rhs )

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

As per the [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp), which says that:

```
template < class T, class U > 
bool operator==( const
std::shared_ptr<T>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<U>& rhs ) noexcept;
```

It indicates `lhs` and `rhs` could be different types. What surprises me is that the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/r5h8bEEWf) below does not compile. I fully understand what the compiler complains. What **confuses** me is **the said document says** the `lhs` and `rhs` could be different types.

Here is the said code snippet:

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

struct Widget
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int var;
};

int main()
{
    auto wp{std::make_shared<Widget>(std::vector<int>{1,2,3}, 69)};

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> vp{wp, &wp->vec};

    std::cout << wp.owner_before(vp) << std::endl;
    std::cout << vp.owner_before(wp) << std::endl;

    std::cout << (wp==vp) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: For a simple use-case: Think about when you have inheritance with polymorphism. You can compare a pointer to a base-class with a pointer to a child-class. That makes sense. Your comparison, comparing a pointer to a `Widget` to a pointer to a `std::vector<int>`, makes less sense.

Answer (score 2):

They can be different types, but they must be comparable. A `Widget*` pointer and a `std::vector<int>*` pointer don't have an `operator==` overload defined, and neither is convertible to the other.

Note that the comparison operators for `shared_ptr` simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared.

Here's an example where comparing different types would work:

```cpp
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

struct foo {};
struct bar : foo{};

int main()
{
    auto f = std::make_shared<foo>();
    auto b = std::make_shared<bar>();

    std::cout << (f == b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think the document should add some restriction to avoid such misleading. How do you think about it? The declaration  indicates `lhs` and `rhs` could be different types.

Comment: @John The C++ specification contains language that makes it clear that ordinary (non-smart) pointers needs to have some kind of relationship (i.e. be convertible to each other) for them to be able to be compared for equality. Since the smart-pointer comparison is defined as comparison of the owned pointers, you need to look at [the ordinary pointer comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Pointer_comparison_operators).

Comment: @John They _can_ be of different types. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

From [std::shared_ptr's operator_cmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp):

> Note that the comparison operators for `shared_ptr` **simply compare pointer values**; the actual objects pointed to are not compared.

Note the highlighted part in the above quoted statement which means that the pointer objects that is handled by the respective `shared_ptr` are compared. And in your example, the pointer objects handled by the respective `share_ptr` are `Widget*` and `std::vector<int>*` which are compared. But since there isn't an overloaded `operator==` that compares a `Widget*` with a `std::vector<int>*`, the program fails to compile.

---

For example, if you derive a `Button` from the `Widget` and then compare `shared_ptr<Widget>` and `shared_ptr<Button>` the program will work.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VtAT8CVBPDH0UQ2x).

Comment: I think the document should add some restriction to avoid such misleading. How do you think about it? The declaration indicates `lhs` and `rhs` could be different types, which is misleading.

Comment: @John In the quoted statement above, it is specifically written that *"simply compare pointer values"* which means(is interpreted as) the pointer objects that is handled by the respective `shared_ptr` are compared. Perhaps you misunderstood this part. And in your example, the pointer objects handled by the respective `share_ptr` are `Widget*` and `std::vector<int>*`.

Comment: I see. *"simply compare pointer values"* works only if when they are the same types or they are polymorphic pointers. Am I right?

Comment: @John Yes if they are related types(due to inheritance) or are same types or convertible. For example, if you derive a `Button` from `Widget` and comapre the `shared_ptr<Widget>` and `shared_ptr<Button>`, it will work.